# Refresh Markers from JSON in Google map without blink

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I´ve been looking in different answers regarding this issue and I still can´t figure how to solve this with my code.

I´m using the example of loading JSON from PHP with Google map API v3.

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-json.html

I´d like to get around `$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');` since that removes all markers in my "update".

- How do I update the map without markers blinking?
- If my result from a new JSON-call differ from actual data already on map, how do I compare and remove/add marker/s?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pageshow', '#map_index', function () {
 
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(58.990738, 16.210006);
                var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 10,
                  center: myLatlng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

               loadMarkers();
});


var loadMarkers = function(){ 

setCenter();
 
 $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
 $.getJSON( 'map/map_json.php', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.markers, function(j, marker) {
   
   if (j == data.markers.length-1){
    ANIMATION = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
   }else{
    ANIMATION = google.maps.Animation.NONE;
   }
   
   
   
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.Latitude, marker.Longitude), 
                'bounds': false,
    'icon': User,
    'animation': ANIMATION
     }).click(function() {
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': 
        '<div id="locTime">'
        +'Tid:&nbsp;'+ marker.Time +'</b>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<div id="LocArea">Area: '+ marker.Area +'</div>'
        +'<div id="locText">'
        +'<p>Larmtext: '+ marker.Text +'</p>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<div id="locPos">Position av Objekt'
        +'<br />Longitude: '+ marker.Longitude
        +'<br />Latitude: '+ marker.Latitude +'</div>'
        
     
     }, this);
              });
     });
});


}

var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ loadMarkers() }, 3000);

   
var setCenter = function(){
 
 $('#map_canvas').gmap('option' ,'center', new google.maps.LatLng(58.990738, 16.210006));
 $('#map_canvas').gmap('option' ,'zoom',12);
 
}     
</script>
<link href="_css/customStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_map/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var User = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map/icons/User.png');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="map_index">
<div data-role="header"> <a href="menu.php" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline" rel="external">Home</a>
 <h1>Map</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="content">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thnx in advance...

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but I think part of the problem could be that you're clearing the map before you run the AJAX request, so while you're waiting for the response the map is empty. You might be able to fix this just by making the `$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');` the first step that happens in the callback for your AJAX request, instead of doing it before initiating the request.

Comment: Can you post an example how I would do that in code?

Comment: The thing i cant get around is howto reload JSON and then update markers with no flicker. My posten code World but as you said, the clear marker make markers blink. What should I use instead? Since new json can be new markers or new states on markers i need to remove them and show them again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with marker blinking. 
my solution ( without jQuery ) :

```
function GMapsCreateMarker(map, lat, lng, markerid) {
        var objLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: objLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'icon/icon.gif' ,
            title: 'my title',
            id: markerid
        });
        map.markers.push(marker); // add in array
        return marker; 
}

function GMapsMarkerLocationUpdate( map, lat, lng, markerid ) {  
    var result = false;  
    for( i=0;i< map.markers.length ; i++ ) {  
            if ( map.markers[i].id == markerid ){  
                //update location on existing marker
                map.markers[i].setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ) );
            result = true;
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

And in your code:

```
$.getJSON( 'map/map_json.php', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.markers, function(j, marker) {
        if ( GMapsMarkerLocationUpdate('map_canvas',  marker.Latitude, marker.Longitude, marker.ID /** your unique id from DB **/) == false ){
            GMapsCreateMarker('map_canvas',  marker.Latitude, marker.Longitude, marker.ID /** your unique id from DB **/ );
        } 
     });
});
```

This example JavaScript is not really tested and can contain syntax errors! But idea is to change location on existing markers and never clear all markers from maps.

Delete/Remove single marker:

```
function GMapsDeleteMarker( map, markerid ) {  
        for( i=0;i< map.markers.length ; i++ ) {  
            if ( map.markers[i].id == markerid ){  
            map.markers[i].setMap(null);
            delete map.markers[i]; //remove from array
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx, i'll try that tomorrow and let you know how it goes. I have seen other examples where ppl uses setPosition instead of removing the markers. Let me get back to you on this.